# How can I enable table level filtering on an MySQL Aurora read replica

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.html#AuroraMySQL.Replication.Filters

I'm trying to get this enabled. I have an Aurora cluster. I've added a read replica. I've assigned it a different parameter group.

The parameter I need 'replicate-do-table' doesn't exist in the parameter group, nor do I see a way to add it via the console.

The article shows doing it via CLI, which gives me an error that the JSON is invalid, and as far as I can tell - it isn't.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share the command that you're running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the misunderstanding is a consequence of "replica" being overloaded with so many meanings.

TL;DR - some of the replication discussion in the doc primarily applies when replicating *outward* from Aurora to some non-Aurora MySQL server. The built-in Aurora replication is physical - comprehensive and efficient, but lacking some of the flexible options of the familiar MySQL replication. There are replication improvements (including filtering) available in Aurora MySQL version 3, so you could do that if your cluster is compatible with MySQL 8.0, but not with MySQL 5.7-compatible or 5.6-compatible ones.

Just on the fundamental JSON syntax level:

> --parameters "[{"ParameterName": "replicate-wild-do-table", "ParameterValue": "mydb.orders%,mydb.returns%", "ApplyMethod":"immediate"}]"

maybe the outer quotes surrounding the whole JSON string should be single quotes.

If you still run into issues, it's worth diving deeper into the kinds of replication you can do with Aurora...

When you have an Aurora cluster and you add instance #2 to it, that instance is an "Aurora replica", also known as a "reader instance". It is associated with the same physical storage devices as instance #1 (the writer instance). That means the reader instance has all the same tables, indexes, partitions, and other schema objects as the writer instance. No filtering is possible. But filtering isn't needed, because there is no duplicate storage consumed on the reader instance by the schema objects and the data they contain. It's all being read off the same storage devices. If the writer instance crashes, the reader instance already has all the data available and so can take over very quickly.

The doc page says:

> You can use replication filters to specify which databases and tables are replicated with a read replica

A "read replica" is a MySQL server outside of Aurora, that you replicate to using Aurora as the source. That *logical* replication (as opposed to the physical replication built into Aurora) has the flexibility to do filtering, delayed replication, nifty things like that. The drawbacks are things like CPU overhead to do the replication, the potential for higher replication lag, and the fact that the replicated data consumes extra storage.

The doc page says:

> The following limitations apply to replication filtering for Aurora MySQL:
> Replication filters are supported only for Aurora MySQL version 3

So depending on which MySQL-compatible edition you're running, filtering might or might not be available. You'll need a MySQL 8.0-compatible cluster.

You will see on pages like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.StorageReliability.html that each Aurora cluster maintains 6 copies of all the cluster data behind the scenes, to guard against hardware failures and to distribute the overhead for reads. But Aurora manages all that invisibly behind the scenes. You don't get a 6x surprise on metrics like "how much storage you are using".

There is even a third kind of replica, an "Aurora read replica". That's when an entire Aurora cluster is a target of incoming replication from a source outside of Aurora. Then the whole Aurora cluster is treated as read-only.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. You can create an Aurora read replica inside RDS for an Aurora cluster, separate from the reader/writer endpoints. And the link I posted suggests you can enable filtering to the replica. As does this link: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/02/amazon-rds-mysql-mariadb-support-replication-filtering/

Comment: And so I missed a very important part of the docs, and your comment. MySQL 8 is required. That was the missing piece for me. Thanks!

Comment: I tried out your scenario using the MySQL 8.0-compatible Aurora edition. I still ran into errors. I checked with others (I work for AWS). The type of replica this feature works with is the "Aurora read replica" where the whole cluster is the target. The params are part of the cluster parameter group, not the instance one. The source must be a different Aurora cluster or RDS MySQL instance. If you CREATE TABLE, INSERT, etc. on an Aurora cluster with a writer instance and 1-15 reader instances, this feature is not applicable - all readers see exactly the same tables and data as on the writer.

Comment: You may have missed my second comment. I totally missed the part in the docs and your comment where MySQL 8 is required. Thank you for the follow up.

Comment: Right. Since I've seen in the past misunderstandings about the interaction of replication and Aurora, I just want to be sure you don't do an upgrade and still run into more issues. Another prerequisite is: you must have to have an external MySQL server doing binlog replication into Aurora. Then do the binlog steps on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.html to make the Aurora cluster accept incoming replication. The Aurora cluster can have a subset of the tables from the external source. The Aurora instances will all have the same tables.